# How to "flatten" a dataframe where one column contains a space-separated list?

Tags: python, pandas

my df looks like this:

```
  A  |   B    | C
1 2 3|location|code
```

what I want to do is make the df look like this:

```
A|   B    |  C
1|location|code
2|location|code
3|location|code
```

effectively repeating the row for each space-separated value in the first column.

Is there a pandas-centric way to do this (instead of iterating over each row and expanding the value in the first column)?

Answer (score 1):

You can first convert the column 'A' to a list using:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str.split(' ')
```

And then use the `explode` method from pandas, see [explode documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df = df.explode('A')
print(df)
```

See the following full example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A' : ["1 2 3"],
    'B' : ["location"],
    'C' : ["code"]
})

df['A'] = df['A'].str.split(' ')
df.explode('A')

>>> A   B           C
    1   location    code
    2   location    code
    3   location    code
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) before [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) your dataframe:

```
>>> df.assign(A=df['A'].str.split('\s+')).explode('A', ignore_index=True)
   A         B     C
0  1  location  code
1  2  location  code
2  3  location  code
```

Intermediate step:

```
>>> df.assign(A=df['A'].str.split('\s+'))
           A         B     C
0  [1, 2, 3]  location  code
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a split explode on the A column and then merge it:

```
df[['B', 'C']].merge(df['A'].str.split().explode(), left_index = True, right_index = True)
```

Comment: Prefer `concat` instead of `merge` here: `pd.concat([df.pop('A').str.split(' ').explode(), df], axis=1)`